# Помогите пожалуйста с программой 1 в C++ Builder 6

Tags: c++builder

Здравствуйте, уважаемые программисты!
Имеется парочка небольших проблем:
***Аналогично данной программе: на мониторе графически представляются так называемые множества Жюлиа необходимо на C++ Builder сделать пару прог таких, чтобы вместо эллипсов пространство Paint Box заполняли:
1)Точки
2)Чёрточки***
Помимо кода на С++ 3-й части, имеется методичка по всем 3 программам на Delphi
***Помогите пожалуйста, буду очень признателен, благодарность в виде денег на мобильный не заставит себя ждать***

***Код 3-й части на C++ Builder:***

```
     //---------------------------------------------------------------------------

#include <vcl.h>
#pragma hdrstop

#include "Unit1.h"
#include <math.h>
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma resource "*.dfm"
TForm1 *Form1;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner)
        : TForm(Owner)
{
}

float  RE,IM,RE1,IM1;

 // вывод точки заданного цвета
void TForm1::putpixel(int x, int y, int c)
{
 TColor cc;

 switch (c % 8)
  {
 case 0:{cc=clBlack;break;}
 case 1:{cc=clRed;break;}
 case 2:{cc=clLime;break;}
 case 3:{cc=clYellow;break;}
 case 4:{cc=clBlue;break;}
 case 5:{cc=clFuchsia;break;}
 case 6:{cc=clAqua;break;}
 case 7:{cc=clWhite;break;}
  }
 PaintBox1->Canvas->Pixels[x][y] = cc;
}



void TForm1::KUB(void)
{
 RE1=RE*(RE*RE-3*IM*IM);
 IM1=IM*(3*RE*RE-IM*IM);
 RE=RE1;
 IM=IM1;
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
int i,x,y,V, X, Y, x2, y2;

randomize();
PaintBox1->Canvas->Brush->Color = RGB(0,0,0);
PaintBox1->Canvas->FillRect(Rect(0,0, 640,480));
for (i=1; i<300; i++)
{
 x=random(100);
 y=random(100);
 PaintBox1->Canvas->Pixels[x][y]=RGB(random(255),random(255),random(255) );

 PaintBox1->Canvas->Pen->Color = RGB(random(255),random(255),random(255));
 PaintBox1->Canvas->Pen->Width = random(3)+1;
 x = random(100);
 y = random(100);
 PaintBox1->Canvas->MoveTo(x,y);
 x = random(100);
 y = random(100);
 PaintBox1->Canvas->LineTo(x,y);

 // цвет и ширина каймы будущего эллипса
 PaintBox1->Canvas->Pen->Color = RGB(random(255),random(255),random(255)) ;
 PaintBox1->Canvas->Pen->Width = random(3)+1;
 // цвет заливки внутренности эллипса
 PaintBox1->Canvas->Brush->Color = RGB(random(255),random(255),random(255)) ;
 // координаты углов прямоугольника, в который вписывается эллипс
 x = random(150);
 y = random(150);
 x2 = random(150);
 y2 = random(150);
 // впиисываем эллипс
 //PaintBox1->Canvas->Ellipse(x,y,x2,y2);
 PaintBox1->Canvas->FillRect(Rect(x,y,x2,y2));
}
// Множества Жюлиа
PaintBox1->Canvas->Brush->Color = RGB(0,0,0);
PaintBox1->Canvas->FillRect(Rect(0,0, 640,480));
X=-320 ;
do {
 Y=-240 ;
 do {
  V=0 ; RE=-1.+0.001*X ; IM=0+0.001*Y ;
  do {
   KUB();
   RE=RE+1.00003 ; IM=IM+1.01828201638 ;
   if (RE*RE > 50)  break;
   if (IM*IM > 50)  break;
   V=V+1 ;
   }
  while (V<40) ;
  if (( abs(RE) >  10 ) || ( abs(IM) > 1000)  )
  {
   putpixel((X+320),(Y+240),V) ;
  }
  else putpixel((X+320),(Y+240),0);
  Y=Y+1 ;
  }
 while (Y < 241) ;
 X=X+1 ;
 }
while (X < 320) ;

}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

***Методичка всех 3-х прог на Delphi***

```
Для рисования статичных рисунков используется компонент PaintBox (панель System). Этот компонент размещается на форме в виде прозрачного пунктирного квадрата, и в его пределах можно рисовать. Рисование выполняется обращением к свойству Canvas (графическая канва) этого компонента: PaintBox1.Canvas. У него в свою очередь есть свойство Pixels (PaintBox1.Canvas.Pixels), которое представляет собой матрицу, двумерный массив заданного размера - поточечный образ канвы, каждый элемент - отдельная точка. В Pixels[] отсчет точек (пикселов экрана) начинается с 0. Координаты x, y отсчитываются от верхнего левого угла, то есть он считается точкой с координатой (0, 0), увеличение по оси x идет слева направо, а по оси y - сверху вниз. Для конкретной точки указывается цвет. Функция RGB() формирует цвет комбинацией интенсивности красного, зеленого и синего (интенсивность задается числом от 0 до 255).
```

Например, черный - RGB(0,0,0), красный - rgb(255,0,0), синий - rgb(0,0,255), белый - rgb(255,255,255).
Цель работы - создать программу, выполняющую следующие действия:
1. Разместить на форме компонент PaintBox.
2. Заполнить доступную канву 300 красными точками в случайных позициях по нажатиям
на некоторую кнопку.
3. Для выхода из программы необходимо щелкнуть мышью на закрывающей кнопке в
строке заголовка.
4. Записать код в обработчике нажатия.

Рис. 1

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var i,x,y: Integer;
begin
randomize;
for i := 1 to 300 do
begin
x := random(100);
y := random(100);
PaintBox1.Canvas.Pixels[x,y] := RGB(255,0,0);
end
end;
```

5. Изменить RGB(255,0,0) на RGB(random(255),random(255),random(255) ).

Рис. 2

6. Заполнить фон черным цветом перед началом выполнения программы с помощью метода канвы FillRect. Метод вызывается с указанием прямоугольной области заливки цветом: FillRect(Rect(0, 0, 100, 100)) // координаты верхнего левого и правого нижнего углов Вложенное слово Rect формирует данное типа "прямоугольник". Перед вызовом FillRect надо указать цвет заливки: PaintBox1.Canvas.Brush.Color := RGB(0,0,0);

Рис. 3

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var i,x,y: Integer;
begin
PaintBox1.Canvas.Brush.Color := RGB(0,0,0);
PaintBox1.Canvas.FillRect(Rect(0,0,100,100));
for i := 1 to 300 do
begin
x := random(100);
y := random(100);
PaintBox1.Canvas.Pixels[x,y] := RGB(random(255),random(255),random(255));
end
end;
7. Заполнить канву случайными разноцветными линиями разной толщины. Линия рисуется с помощью методов (сначала задается начальная точка, потом конечная):
PaintBox1.Canvas.MoveTo(10,10);
PaintBox1.Canvas.LineTo(50,50);
```

Цвет линии и толщина задаются свойством канвы Pen (карандаш). Pen.Color - цвет
карандаша), Pen.Width - толщина линии в пикселах (по умолчанию - 1).

Рис. 4

```
for i := 1 to 300 do
begin
PaintBox1.Canvas.Pen.Color := RGB(random(255),random(255),random(255));
PaintBox1.Canvas.Pen.Width := random(3)+1;
x := random(100);
y := random(100);
PaintBox1.Canvas.MoveTo(x,y);
x := random(100);
y := random(100);
PaintBox1.Canvas.LineTo(x,y);
end
```

8. Заполнить канву эллипсами случайным образом (круги, окружности - частный случай
   эллипса). Эллипсы рисуются методом Ellipse() с четырьмя параметрами - координатами
   верхнего левого и правого нижнего углов прямоугольника, в который эллипс вписывается. Кайма эллипса рисуется в соответствии с параметрами свойства Pen канвы, а заливается эллипс внутри цветом кисти Brush канвы.

Рис. 5.

```
for i := 1 to 300 do
begin
// цвет и ширина каймы будущего эллипса
PaintBox1.Canvas.Pen.Color := RGB(random(255),random(255),random(255)) ;
PaintBox1.Canvas.Pen.Width := random(3)+1;
// цвет заливки внутренности эллипса
PaintBox1.Canvas.Brush.Color := rgb(random(255),random(255),random(255)) ;
// координаты углов прямоугольника, в который вписывается эллипс
x := random(150);
y := random(150);
x2 := random(150);
y2 := random(150);
// вписываем эллипс
PaintBox1.Canvas.Ellipse(x,y,x2,y2);
end;
```

9. Сделать канву на весь экран. Заполнить разноцветными прямоугольниками в случайных
   позициях и случайных размеров с помощью FillRect().
10. Создать графический образ так называемого множества Жюлиа.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var RE,IM,RE1,IM1: REAL ;
V,X,Y : INTEGER;
// вывод точки заданного цвета
procedure PUTPIXEL(x,y,c:Integer);
var cc: TColor;
begin
case c mod 8 of
0:cc:=clBlack;
1:cc:=clRed;
2:cc:=clLime;
3:cc:=clYellow;
4:cc:=clBlue;
5:cc:=clFuchsia;
6:cc:=clAqua;
7:cc:=clWhite;
end;
PaintBox1.Canvas.Pixels[x,y] := cc;
end;
procedure QWA ;
begin
RE1:=RE*RE-IM*IM;
IM1:=2*RE*IM;
RE:=RE1;
IM:=IM1;
end;
procedure KUB;
begin
RE1:=RE*(RE*RE-3*IM*IM);
IM1:=IM*(3*RE*RE-IM*IM);
RE:=RE1;
IM:=IM1;
end ;
Begin
PaintBox1.Canvas.Brush.Color := rgb(0,0,0);
PaintBox1.Canvas.FillRect(Rect(0,0,640,480));
X:=-320 ;
REPEAT Y:=-240 ;
REPEAT V:=0 ; RE:=-1.+0.001*X ; IM:=0+0.001*Y ;
REPEAT KUB; RE:=RE+1.00003 ; IM:=IM+1.01828201638 ;
if RE*RE > 50 then break;
if IM*IM > 50 then break;
V:=V+1 ;
UNTIL V>40 ;
if ( ABS(RE) > 10 ) or ( ABS(IM) > 1000)
then
begin
PUTPIXEL((X+320),(Y+240),TRUNC(V)) ;
end
else PUTPIXEL((X+320),(Y+240),0);
Y:=Y+1 ;
UNTIL Y > 241 ;
X:=X+1 ;
UNTIL X>320 ;
End;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ве так же как и в исходнике, только выкинь рисование прямоугольника ограничивающего элипс, а в место Elipse пиши Pixels

```
for (int i= 0;i<300;i++) 
{x = random(150); y = random(150); PaintBox1->Canvas->Pixels[x,y] = RGB(255,0,0);}
```